mv "Input/output error" when trying to rename a file on a usb connected phone
I'm trying to use a bash script to replace an old file on my phone with a newer one from my laptop. First I want to rename the file on the phone and then move it to a backup folder.
To rename I run this command:
mv --verbose --backup=numbered "/run/user/1000/gvfs/mtp:host=OnePlus_OnePlus_645cea20/Internal shared storage/Files/test.kdbx" "/run/user/1000/gvfs/mtp:host=OnePlus_OnePlus_645cea20/Internal shared storage/Files/test.kdbx.old"

Which returns:
mv: cannot move '/run/user/1000/gvfs/mtp:host=OnePlus_OnePlus_645cea20/Internal shared storage/Files/test.kdbx' to '/run/user/1000/gvfs/mtp:host=OnePlus_OnePlus_645cea20/Internal shared storage/Files/test.kdbx_2024-08-26_113426.old': Input/output error

How do I rename the file correctly?
I am running Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS.

Update 2:
As suggested by undefined, I tried using gio move to transfer the file and got the following error:
gio: mtp://OnePlus_OnePlus_645cea20/Internal%20shared%20storage/Files/test.kdbx: libmtp error:  could not move object.


Update 1:
Based on advice from the comments I ran sudo dmesg -T. I did multiple checks in the process of plugging in my phone, running the script, and unplugging.
When plugging in to a computer my phone requires me to switch modes from 'No data transfer,' to 'File Transfer' before I can access files on my laptop. I note those stages below.
There were no new entries after running my mv script and getting the error above.
These are the results I got:
Plugging in
[Wed Aug 28 11:53:38 2024] usb 3-1: new high-speed USB device number 20 using xhci_hcd
[Wed Aug 28 11:53:38 2024] usb 3-1: New USB device found, idVendor=05c6, idProduct=f000, bcdDevice= 4.09
[Wed Aug 28 11:53:38 2024] usb 3-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[Wed Aug 28 11:53:38 2024] usb 3-1: Product: OnePlus
[Wed Aug 28 11:53:38 2024] usb 3-1: Manufacturer: OnePlus
[Wed Aug 28 11:53:38 2024] usb 3-1: SerialNumber: 645cea20
[Wed Aug 28 11:53:38 2024] usb-storage 3-1:1.1: USB Mass Storage device detected
[Wed Aug 28 11:53:38 2024] scsi host6: usb-storage 3-1:1.1
[Wed Aug 28 11:53:39 2024] scsi 6:0:0:0: CD-ROM            OnePlus  Device Driver    0409 PQ: 0 ANSI: 2
[Wed Aug 28 11:53:39 2024] sr 6:0:0:0: Power-on or device reset occurred
[Wed Aug 28 11:53:39 2024] sr 6:0:0:0: [sr1] scsi-1 drive
[Wed Aug 28 11:53:39 2024] sr 6:0:0:0: Attached scsi CD-ROM sr1
[Wed Aug 28 11:53:39 2024] sr 6:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg2 type 5
[Wed Aug 28 11:53:40 2024] ISO 9660 Extensions: Microsoft Joliet Level 3
[Wed Aug 28 11:53:40 2024] ISOFS: changing to secondary root
[Wed Aug 28 11:53:40 2024] audit: type=1400 audit(1724864020.433:326): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" class="file" profile="snap.firefox.firefox" name="/etc/fstab" pid=3550 comm="firefox" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=0
[Wed Aug 28 11:53:44 2024] usb 3-1: reset high-speed USB device number 20 using xhci_hcd
[Wed Aug 28 11:53:44 2024] sr 6:0:0:0: Power-on or device reset occurred
[Wed Aug 28 11:53:44 2024] usb 3-1: reset high-speed USB device number 20 using xhci_hcd
[Wed Aug 28 11:53:44 2024] sr 6:0:0:0: Power-on or device reset occurred

Switching to 'File Transfer' mode
[Wed Aug 28 11:56:30 2024] usb 3-1: USB disconnect, device number 20
[Wed Aug 28 11:56:30 2024] audit: type=1400 audit(1724864190.532:327): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" class="file" profile="snap.firefox.firefox" name="/etc/fstab" pid=3550 comm="firefox" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=0
[Wed Aug 28 11:56:30 2024] usb 3-1: new high-speed USB device number 21 using xhci_hcd
[Wed Aug 28 11:56:30 2024] usb 3-1: New USB device found, idVendor=2a70, idProduct=f003, bcdDevice= 4.09
[Wed Aug 28 11:56:30 2024] usb 3-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[Wed Aug 28 11:56:30 2024] usb 3-1: Product: OnePlus
[Wed Aug 28 11:56:30 2024] usb 3-1: Manufacturer: OnePlus
[Wed Aug 28 11:56:30 2024] usb 3-1: SerialNumber: 645cea20

Running script
<No new entries>

Switching back to 'No data transfer'
[Wed Aug 28 12:02:11 2024] usb 3-1: USB disconnect, device number 21
[Wed Aug 28 12:02:11 2024] usb 3-1: new high-speed USB device number 22 using xhci_hcd
[Wed Aug 28 12:02:12 2024] usb 3-1: New USB device found, idVendor=05c6, idProduct=f000, bcdDevice= 4.09
[Wed Aug 28 12:02:12 2024] usb 3-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[Wed Aug 28 12:02:12 2024] usb 3-1: Product: OnePlus
[Wed Aug 28 12:02:12 2024] usb 3-1: Manufacturer: OnePlus
[Wed Aug 28 12:02:12 2024] usb 3-1: SerialNumber: 645cea20
[Wed Aug 28 12:02:12 2024] usb-storage 3-1:1.1: USB Mass Storage device detected
[Wed Aug 28 12:02:12 2024] scsi host6: usb-storage 3-1:1.1
[Wed Aug 28 12:02:13 2024] scsi 6:0:0:0: CD-ROM            OnePlus  Device Driver    0409 PQ: 0 ANSI: 2
[Wed Aug 28 12:02:13 2024] sr 6:0:0:0: Power-on or device reset occurred
[Wed Aug 28 12:02:13 2024] sr 6:0:0:0: [sr1] scsi-1 drive
[Wed Aug 28 12:02:13 2024] sr 6:0:0:0: Attached scsi CD-ROM sr1
[Wed Aug 28 12:02:13 2024] sr 6:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg2 type 5
[Wed Aug 28 12:02:13 2024] ISO 9660 Extensions: Microsoft Joliet Level 3
[Wed Aug 28 12:02:13 2024] ISOFS: changing to secondary root
[Wed Aug 28 12:02:13 2024] audit: type=1400 audit(1724864533.902:328): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" class="file" profile="snap.firefox.firefox" name="/etc/fstab" pid=3550 comm="firefox" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=0
[Wed Aug 28 12:02:17 2024] usb 3-1: reset high-speed USB device number 22 using xhci_hcd
[Wed Aug 28 12:02:17 2024] sr 6:0:0:0: Power-on or device reset occurred
[Wed Aug 28 12:02:17 2024] usb 3-1: reset high-speed USB device number 22 using xhci_hcd
[Wed Aug 28 12:02:18 2024] sr 6:0:0:0: Power-on or device reset occurred

Unmounting through Ubuntu
[Wed Aug 28 12:03:07 2024] audit: type=1400 audit(1724864588.134:329): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" class="file" profile="snap.firefox.firefox" name="/etc/fstab" pid=3550 comm="firefox" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=0

Unplugging
[Wed Aug 28 12:05:52 2024] usb 3-1: USB disconnect, device number 22


You check dmesg output and figure out why the PC lost the connection to the phone ...

Can you give me some more context? I get a ton of information when I run dmesg and I don't know what I'm looking for. ❔

Look for anything pertaining to USB or lines that have OnePlus in them ... either way: your PC has lost connectivity to your phone (or worse, your phone's internal storage has become corrupted), and there's no way to rename things from there.

Did you try sudo?

Do you mean using sudo mv?

@tink I updated with data from dmesg. I didn't get any entries after running my script and it failing. I hope this is helpful.

instead of mv to rename a file on a gvfs (gio virtual file system), use gio, specifically gio rename.
gio is in the libglib2.0-bin package in ubuntu 22.04/"jammy".
virtual file systems are tricky, because depending on their implementation and underlying transport protocol (eg mtp), their behavior might deviate from a native linux filesystem (eg ext[234]), and so support for common unix utilities.

Thanks for your help!
Looking at the man page for gio I'm not sure how to use rename for this.
"[gio] rename LOCATION NAME"
It doesn't allow for slashes in the name, so I can't rename something to another location.
What am I missing?
❔

when saying a command doesn't work, please include the command with its output, otherwise people are left to guess what you executed.
gio rename /path/to/directory/on/phone/file.txt file.txt.old
it doesn't move files between directories, but only renames files.  so reference the file and provide the new filename.  not the new path, because a new path is not allowed; only a new filename.

Ah, I see the confusion. My mistake. Thank you! ✨

The gio suite solved my problems. Thanks for introducing it to me! ✨
